# How to add more voices to Microsoft Text to Speech engine?

Tags: windows-xp, audio, text-to-speech-voices

I'm currently using **Microsoft Windows XP** which comes bundled with the **Microsoft Sam Voice.**

I want to add more voices as Sam is not very good to work with.

Many dictionary software's that i use take the default Microsoft voice for pronouncing and demonstrating new words and sentences.

Are there any voices (ideally free, but no limitations can be paid too) available that will add-on directly to the default windows text to speech engine ?

Can I **set one of those voices** as a **default** instead of **Sam**?  **I don't need a text to speech reader software** so i need **only the voices,** not bundled with any software.

Also please suggest voices which are **natural.**

Comment: "I want to add more voices as Sam is not very good to work with." Bad Sam, bad Sam.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft TTS for supports 2 other english voices, Mike and Mary, [MSM files downloadable here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/4/3/B4314928-7B71-4336-9DE7-6FA4CF00B7B3/Sp5TTIntXP.exe) and a slew of foreign language voices as well.

---

For convenience, I wrapped it in an MSI (drag and drop w/ VS.NET) [downloadable here](http://www.hyperslug.com/tts/xptts.msi).  The process for that is detailed here: http://blogs.msdn.com/robertbrown/archive/2005/04/21/410561.aspx.

Comment: Downloaded and installed these but Microsoft Sam is still the only option when i go to control panel- speech and try to change the voice.. can't change the default voice inspite of the installation

Comment: Tsk, I apologize Rogue, shame on me for not verifying.  This is an unzips an MSM file to your temp directory which requires you to build an MSI -> http://blogs.msdn.com/robertbrown/archive/2005/04/21/410561.aspx, and then run it.  It used to be so much simpler, I remember grabbing a bunch of them quickly.

Comment: damn.. didn't think Microsoft would make it that inconvenient.. i mean c'mon build an msi just to install free voices.. geez.. its not shame on u hyperslug you're the good guy, it's shame on Microsoft for making it so stupidly inconvenient when a better voice (or rather these voices) could have been bundled in windows in the first place

Comment: Rogue, I made an MSI for you http://www.hyperslug.com/tts/xptts.msi.  Post here and let me know if it worked.  Just run it.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get them from [third parties](http://www.microsoft.com/speech/evaluation/thirdparty/engines.mspx).